# Int to small for string iteration using boost::string_ref

Tags: c++, string, performance, boost

I'm writing something like a tokenizer.
I would like to use `boost::string_ref` to return "token values".
I want to iterate over string_ref reading char by char and then return substring including the value.

Lets take a look at very minimalistic example:

```
string test = "testing string";
boost::string_ref rtest(test);

//-------- and now we can go this way --------
auto begin = rtest.begin();
auto end   = rtest.end();
for(/*something*/){
    process_char(*end); // print char
    end ++;
}
// how to return rtest(begin,end)?

// -------- or this way --------
int begin = 0;
int end   = 0;
for(/*something*/){
    process_char(rtest[end]);
    end++;
}
return rtest.substr(begin, end);
```

In the code there are shown two ways of iterating over string: with pointer and with int.
The pointer way is good, but then there is no way to return `boost::string_ref.substr` between pointers and the second methods use ints and int can handle some numbers, which can be to small for large input files.

So is it possible to iterate this way over a large input?

Comment: what kind of values are looking for in the substring. because if your looking for a key char such as "=". then you could just do a find. get the location. then substr ur value out. and return the original string.

Comment: I'm not looking for specyfic values - I want to iterate over EACH character and build from them tokens - it should work as a **tokenizer**. I want to iterate over the string with most performance available way (so I should use pointers perhaps) and the output value can have lenght bigger than int capacity (so it should return `boost::string_ref` over the original string pointers).

Comment: Boost has `string_ref` now?  I've been waiting for that.  I wonder how it slipped my notice.

Comment: the problem with returning a `boost::string_ref` is that once the scope closes and it is returned. it is deleted off because it is out of scope. i would suggest boost::move as it would be better practice. to move the data to ur return value. rather then refrencing it as it will be deleted apon scope close (unless it was a pointer)

Comment: @Zanven - of course, but I dont want to copy anything - the tokenizer keeps the `boost::string_ref` instance and will delete it after all tokens and of course the functions will return pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a sub-string given two pointers, do this:

```
return boost::string_ref(begin, end-begin);
```

Just make sure your reference string exists in the scope you are returning to.

Comment: and what if size of `end-begin` is bigger than int can be?

Comment: additional is this solution not slower than hand coded `string_ref`? Everytime I'm doing `end-begin` the `string_ref` searches internally for `end` value so the work is done 2 times...

Comment: i would personally typecast it then to a `long`. and then check if it is small enough to be an `int`. 

but since you are expecting some or all to be longer then a `int`. then shoudlnt you jsut store them all as `long`'s? you only use the size of a varriable you actually need. which is why i use `shorts` alot when `int` is not needed. and in this case `long` appears to be needed.

Comment: @danilo2: So, what if it is?  What does `int` have to do with this?  If, on your system, a pointer subtraction results in an int, then an int, by definition, is guaranteed to be able to hold the difference between two pointers.

Comment: When you do `end-begin`, the `string_ref` does not do any searching.  It's just a pointer subtraction.  Few operations could possibly be faster.

Comment: @BenjaminLidley thank you. Could you please tell me if `string_ref` really does not do any searching? Lets say you want to compare the substring to a string - than the string_ref will iterate over `begin` up to `end=begin+delta`, so if I will often return such substring and compare them, thay will always do `delta=end-begin` and then `end=begin+delta`, wont they?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but: If you compare (as in, `operator==`) a `string_ref` against a `string`, it's going to first compare their sizes to see if it can make an early exit.  If the sizes are not the same, it will compare character by character up until the first different character.  does that answer your question?  If not, you'll need to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you, you are right - if the implemenetation of these methods is good, my concerns are not valid anymore. But there is other problem - when `begin` is `std::string::iterator` your code does not work - how to implement it with such assumption the "pretty way" ?

Comment: `return boost::string_ref(&*begin, end-begin);` -- I can't answer your other question.  Ask the maintainers of the library.  You can find them on the boost mailing list.